# Why does $F(x,y)=\int g(x,y)dx+h(y)$ hold?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I know that if $F(x,y)$ is a function of two variables and $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}=g(x,y)$ then it follows that

$$F(x,y)=\int g(x,y)dx+h(y)\cdots(1)$$ for some function $h$ of $y$ and $\int g(x,y)dx$ has been evaluated keeping $y$ fixed.

I am having trouble to understand why $(1)$ follows?

Is there any related result or theorem that enable us to write $(1)$ under given condition?

Comment: Are you okay with the fact that $F(x)=\int F'(x)dx +c$?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur yes I know that fact

Comment: For a fixed $y_0$ define  $F_{y_0}(x):=F(x,y_0)$ and $g_{y_0}(x)=g(x,y_0)$. By the above fact you conclude that $F_{y_0}(x)=\int g_{y_0}(x)dx+c_{y_0}$. Define finally $h(y_0):=c_{y_0}$ for all $y_0$.

Comment: You're right. Integrating a 2 variable function $F(x,y)$ usually means doing a double integral. Likewise, integrating a 3 variable function $F(x,y,z)$ would usually indicate a triple integral. However, by asking this question, you have actually glossed over something that you thought you understood, but in actuality you didn't (happens to me frequently and to everyone). For the same reason that you can take "single derivatives" of multi-variable functions, you can take single integrals of multivariable functions. You wrote down $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}$. If you are okay with this, you

Comment: you should be able to understand your question. I hope this helps. By the way, $\int g(x,y) dx$ means that, for every single $y$, you have a single integral. That's a lot of single integrals. Therefore, we need a lot of constants. I.e. we need $h(y)$ for a constant. For this $y$, you have this single integral and this constant. For another $y$, you have another single integral and another constant. Etc.