# Exact form $\alpha$ and $dg=\alpha$

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-forms, differential

> Let $\alpha= f_1(x_1,x_2)dx_1 + f_2(x_1,x_2)dx_2$ such that
>   $d\alpha=0$. Define a function $g$ by $$g(x_1,x_2)= \int_{0}^{x_1} f_1(t,x_2) dt + \int_{0}^{x_2} f_2(0,t)dt$$ Show that $dg=\alpha$

By $d\alpha=0$ we get $\dfrac{\partial{f_2}}{\partial{x_1}}-\dfrac{\partial{f_1}}{\partial{x_2}}=0$ and 
$$dg= \dfrac{\partial}{\partial{x_1}} ( \int_{0}^{x_1} f_1(t,x_2) dt ) dx_1+\dfrac{\partial}{\partial{x_2}}(\int_{0}^{x_1} f_1(t,x_2) dt) dx_2$$

$$+\dfrac{\partial}{\partial{x_1}}(\int_{0}^{x_2} f_2(0,t) dt) dx_1 +\dfrac{\partial}{\partial{x_2}}(\int_{0}^{x_2} f_2(0,t) dt) dx_2$$
By [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule)

$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial{x_1}} ( \int_{0}^{x_1} f_1(t,x_2) dt ) =f_1(x_1,x_2) + ( \int_{0}^{x_1}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial{x_1}} f_1(t,x_2) dt ) $

$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial{x_2}}(\int_{0}^{x_1} f_1(t,x_2) dt)=(\int_{0}^{x_1} \dfrac{\partial}{\partial{x_2}}f_1(t,x_2) dt)$

$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial{x_1}}(\int_{0}^{x_2} f_2(0,t) dt)=(\int_{0}^{x_2} \dfrac{\partial}{\partial{x_1}}f_2(0,t) dt)$

$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial{x_2}}(\int_{0}^{x_2} f_2(0,t) dt)=f_2(0,x_2)+(\int_{0}^{x_2}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial{x_2}} f_2(0,t) dt)$

Do i have any mistake? And can you continue to compute those and indicate $dg=\alpha$?

Comment: You only need to use Leibniz's integral rule 1 time and not 4 times. Check out my comment [to this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2940686/why-does-fx-y-int-gx-ydxhy-hold#comment6074345_2940686). It's all about understanding what a single integral of a multivariable function is. Once you see this, then use what we know from single variable calculus: $\frac{d}{dx}\int_a^x f = f(x)$. Therefore your first line, 3rd line, and 4th line under the link you give is just applying this result. Only the 2nd line do you need leibniz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fine so far. Now 
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} f_1(t,x_2) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} f_2(0,t) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_2} f_2(0,t) = 0.$$
Why?
All that you have left to do is use the hypothesis that $d\alpha=0$ to rewrite
$$\int_0^{x_1} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_2} f_1(t,x_2)dt = \int_0^{x_1}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} f_2(t,x_2)dt,$$
and finish the computation.

Comment: thank you @Ted Shifrin

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept the answer when you are satisfied and have no further questions, so that the question will not stay on the "unanswered" list.